# If a real algebraic variety is "the same" at every point, is it always a manifold?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, affine-varieties

I'm studying a real algebraic variety $S$ (embedded in a real Euclidean space) that is "the same at every point" in the following sense:  for any two points $p, q \in S$, there is a homeomorphism from $S$ to $S$ that maps $p$ to $q$.  (If it helps, that homeomorphism is just an invertible **linear** transformation in the ambient Euclidean space.)

Does this imply that $S$ is a manifold?  If so, where should I look for the math to verify it?  If not, can you think of a counterexample?

An obvious implication of this property is that either every point has an open neighborhood homeomorphic to a ball (hence $S$ is a manifold) or **no** point has an open neighborhood homeomorphic to a ball.  So a closely related question is:  does there exist a real algebraic variety in which no point has an open neighborhood homeomorphic to a ball?  (If "no", then the answer to my first question is "yes".)

BTW, I need an answer to the first question for a research paper I'm writing.

Comment: If I understand correctly, for your variety $V\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ you require that given any to points $p$, $q\in V$ there exists a $f:V\rightarrow V$, restriction of a linear transformation of $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $f(p)=q$. Are there any such $V$'s besides linear varieties?

Comment: or maybe a few quadrics?

Comment: @AndreaMori: You understand correctly. The variety I'm interested in is multilinear, and it can be of any degree. It arises from placing an upper bound on the ranks of several real matrices. (The components of those matrices are variables of the variety, or polynomials on the variables.) A bound on a real matrix's rank can be expressed as a real algebraic variety by setting all the matrix minors of suitable size to have determinant zero.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/262589/every-real-variety-contains-non-singular-points

I think that what this question is asking to prove (and the top answer) may give what you need.